# PHP register form not working (for some variables)

Tags: php, html

Hey my PHP code for my register form isn't working with some of the var's but everything looks fine to me.

Username, password and email works fine, I also have another page that adds data to the database and that works perfect with the same code as this.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username'";
echo $sql;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($num >= 1){
    $_SESSION['userError']='Username Already Taken';

}else{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = hash('sha256', $password);
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO members(username, password, fname, lname, email, address, contact) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$address', '$contact')";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    echo $sql2;
    $_SESSION['message']="Account Added Successfully";  }} ?>
```

And here is the form that it links too.

```
<form class="pure-form reg-form" action="" method="post">
                                    <fieldset class="pure-group" style="float:left">
                                        <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" autofocus/>
                                        <input type="password" class="pure-input-1" name="password" value="" pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{4,}" placeholder="Password"/>
                                        <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" name"fname" value="" placeholder="First Name"/>
                                        <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" name"lname" value="" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset class="pure-group" style="float:right">
                                        <input type="email" class="pure-input-1" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail"/>
                                        <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" name"address" value="" placeholder="Address"/>
                                        <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" name"contact" value="" placeholder="Contact"/>
                                        <input type="submit" class="pure-button pure-input-1 pure-button-primary" name="submit" value="Submit">
                                    </fieldset>   
                                </form>
```

Comment: can you write value of `$sql2` variable in your question.

Comment: also make sure that `db` schema for the table `members` allows the values you are trying to insert, e.g maybe an empty `contact` string is not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Your `HTML` you are missing `=` from some of the input tags

Your Code :

```
<form class="pure-form reg-form" action="" method="post">
                                <fieldset class="pure-group" style="float:left">
                                    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" autofocus/>
                                    <input type="password" class="pure-input-1" name="password" value="" pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{4,}" placeholder="Password"/>
                                    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" name"fname" value="" placeholder="First Name"/>//missing = 
                                    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" name"lname" value="" placeholder="Last Name"/>//missing = 
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset class="pure-group" style="float:right">
                                    <input type="email" class="pure-input-1" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail"/>
                                    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" name"address" value="" placeholder="Address"/> //missing = 
                                    <input type="text" class="pure-input-1" name"contact" value="" placeholder="Contact"/>  //missing = 
                                    <input type="submit" class="pure-button pure-input-1 pure-button-primary" name="submit" value="Submit">
                                </fieldset>   
                            </form>
```

And Also check your `PHP` code your are making query in `sql2` and executing `sql`

change :

```
   $sql2 = "INSERT INTO members(username, password, fname, lname, email, address, contact) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$address', '$contact')";
mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

to :

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO members(username, password, fname, lname, email, address, contact) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$address', '$contact')";
mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Thank you, god its just those little things that you miss.

Answer (score 0):

you write query but not execute it.

line 22

```
 mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

change $sql  to $sql2